# Inserting to new table in between two table in ms word from vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Please someone help me out. I want to insert new table in ms word from vb.net application, I use bookmark to define the range but it still give error

> the range cannot be delete

below is my code.

```
Public Sub invoicePrinting1(ByVal strBasePath As String, ByVal userid As String)
    Dim oWord = New Word.Application With {.Visible = False}
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Open(strBasePath)
    Dim pos, len As Integer
    Dim reg As Regex
    Dim bookmarkName As String
    Dim rng As Object
    Dim search As String = "@@Item_List1@@"
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = printbox.DGVacct


    Dim headers = (From ch In dgv.Columns
                   Let header = DirectCast(DirectCast(ch, DataGridViewColumn).HeaderCell, DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell)
                   Select header.Value).ToArray()
    Dim headerText() As String = Array.ConvertAll(headers, Function(v) v.ToString)

    Dim items() = (From r In dgv.Rows
                   Let row = DirectCast(r, DataGridViewRow)
                   Where Not row.IsNewRow
                   Select (From cell In row.Cells
                           Let c = DirectCast(cell, DataGridViewCell)
                           Select c.Value).ToArray()).ToArray()

    Dim table As String = String.Join(vbTab, headerText) & Environment.NewLine
    For Each a In items
        Dim t() As String = Array.ConvertAll(a, Function(v) v.ToString)
        table &= String.Join(vbTab, t) & Environment.NewLine
    Next

    table = table.TrimEnd(CChar(Environment.NewLine))
    Clipboard.SetText(table)

    ' keyword that you want to search
    reg = New Regex(search)
    ' find the text in word file
    Dim m As Match = reg.Match(oDoc.Range.Text, 0)
    pos = m.Index

    ' start is the starting position of the token in the content...
    len = search.Length
    ' select the text
    rng = oDoc.Range(pos, len + pos)

    bookmarkName = "MyBookmarkName"
    oDoc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmarkName, rng)
    Dim tdRange As Word.Range = oDoc.Range(0, pos)
    With tdRange
        .Collapse(Direction:=Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
        .InsertParagraphAfter()
        .Collapse(Direction:=Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)

    End With
    Dim oTable As Word.Tablespoons = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item(bookmarkName).Range, items.Count + 1, headers.Count)

    oTable.Range.Paste()


    oTable.Range.Font.Size = 9
    'make the first row bold, fs 14 + change textcolor
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Bold = &H98967E
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Size = 10
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Height = 20
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorWhite
    oTable.Range.AutoFormat()

    'change backcolor of first row
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Shading.Texture = Word.WdTextureIndex.wdTextureNone
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorGray25

    'set table borders
    With oTable
        .Columns(1).SetWidth(oDoc.Application.CentimetersToPoints(wd(4.3F)), Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional)
        .Columns(2).SetWidth(oDoc.Application.CentimetersToPoints(wd(10.5F)), Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional)
        .Columns(3).SetWidth(oDoc.Application.CentimetersToPoints(wd(4.8F)), Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional)
        .Columns(4).SetWidth(oDoc.Application.CentimetersToPoints(wd(5.0F)), Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional)
    End With
    'set table borders
    With oTable.Range.Tables(1)


        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth025pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderRight)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth025pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderTop)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth025pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth025pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth025pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderVertical)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth025pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone
        .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone
        .Borders.Shadow = False
        .Rows.Height = 7
    End With

    oDoc.Save()
    oWord.Quit()
    oDoc = Nothing
    oWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: "Dim oTable As Word.Tablespoons = oDoc.Tables.Add" ??? What is a `Word.Tablespoons` object?

Comment: Error.. Not word.tablespoon but word.tables